# Is there a reward for collecting every ring in SegaSonic the Hedgehog?

Tags: segasonic-the-hedgehog

In the 1993 arcade game *SegaSonic the Hedgehog*, when you finish a level you are shown a percentage total for how many rings you managed to collect in the level.

According to the [Sonic Wiki](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/SegaSonic_the_Hedgehog), you receive extra points if you collect at least half of the rings in a level. However, the wiki doesn't say whether you get additional points for collecting *every* ring.

**Is there an additional bonus if you manage to collect every ring in a level?**

[image: Level results screen]

Comment: +1 for a question about a Sonic game I haven't heard about before!

Comment: I really thought this had been tagged incorrectly when I first saw it. Has this game even been ported since it's arcade days?

Comment: @Kozaky No, it has never been rereleased. I came across it because 2 characters from this game, Mighty and Ray, are going to be in Sonic Mania DLC.